# ChatterBot Python

Tags: python, heroku

i just developed a chatterbot web using flask and deployed it on heroku ,but I'm also using a custom myown.yml converstaion and i don't know how to transfer this file on heroku application

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
app = Flask(__name__)
#create chatbot
englishBot = ChatBot("Chatterbot", storage_adapter="chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter")
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(englishBot)
trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english","chatterbot.corpus.custom.myown") #train the chatter bot for english
#define app routes
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
@app.route("/get")
#function for the bot response
def get_bot_response():
    userText = request.args.get('msg')
    return str(englishBot.get_response(userText))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Thanks